# Intellij ide tooltip not showing description on hover

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Whenever I hover it shows the signature but not its description. I have included the screenshot of the same below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA extracts documentation from the JavaDoc comments:

[image]

For `Date` class IDEA shows nothing because the class does not provide a JavaDoc comment (you could open the implementation by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

IDEA allows you to show the online documentation. This could be enabled in the Project Structure window:

[image]

And then IDEA will show you online documentation for the selected class:

[image]

You could also download the offline documentation and attach it by pressing the plus sign.